# Replace specific chinese words in every row of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a long string of Chinese characters but when I try to replace the "headers" of each column, python does not make the replacement:

```
data= pd.DataFrame({'DETAILS': ['厂名: 进口地扪玉米粒 厂址: 进口地扪玉米粒 厂家联系方式: 02081977626 配料.', '厂名: Hill View Packing Co. 厂址: 美国地们 厂家联系方式: 0', '厂名: 5 厂址: 5 厂家联系方式: 5 配料表: 5 储藏方法: 常温 保质期']
                       })
data.DETAILS.replace(['厂名:','厂址:'],'$',inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a regex replace:

```
 lst = ['厂名:','厂址:']

 data['DETAILS'] = data.DETAILS.replace('|'.join(lst), '$', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                                       DETAILS
0  $ 进口地扪玉米粒 $ 进口地扪玉米粒 厂家联系方式: 02081977626 配料.
1     $ Hill View Packing Co. $ 美国地们 厂家联系方式: 0
2        $ 5 $ 5 厂家联系方式: 5 配料表: 5 储藏方法: 常温 保质期
```

Comment: You know, I have been avoiding regex up until this point. I think it's time to learn it once and for all. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Let us try adding `regex=True`, 
From the document :

> to_replacestr, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None

```
data.DETAILS=data.DETAILS.replace(['厂名:','厂址:'],'$',regex=True)
Out[495]: 
0    $ 进口地扪玉米粒 $ 进口地扪玉米粒 厂家联系方式: 02081977626 配料.
1       $ Hill View Packing Co. $ 美国地们 厂家联系方式: 0
2          $ 5 $ 5 厂家联系方式: 5 配料表: 5 储藏方法: 常温 保质期
Name: DETAILS, dtype: object
```